# seafood muscles - how do they work?

Tags: muscles, marine-biology, tissue

Today, first  time in my life I ate seafood. It was a squid and a calamar. Note that I am biology layman, so please be merciful :(

While dissecting my food I noticed that the tissues of those creatures were homogenous white mass. Completely different than with pork or chicken, where you can easily see the directions of muscle fibers and different groups of muscles. Just looking at a chicken wing tells you which muscle does what.

But why are squids and calamars so homogenous? How is it possible they work? Why is it like that?

Comment: As far as I know, the squid's mantle has two layers of muscle, circular and radial muscles, and two layers of epithelium or "tunic." This is unlike animal muscles, where the parts we eat are striated skeletal muscle. The mantle would be more akin to intestinal tissue with circular smooth muscle I'd imagine. That's about all I know, though.